# Redirect from element action

Tags: elementtype, elementaction

I'm trying to process multiple elements in a custom element action, and then redirect the CP user to a url.

How would I do that?

Comment: Entirely possible I'm missing something, but `craft()->request->redirect()`?

Comment: Oh, I kind of assumed the element action made a AJAX request? In which method would you do it? `performAction()`?

Comment: Oh, you're probably right. `includeJs` some JavaScript to do the redirect in `performAction`?